# Converting binary file into PIL Image datatype in Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, image, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I am using Google App Engine with Python and Jinja for the templates. In my HTML template, I have this piece of code, which allows the user to choose a file (Image):

```
    <form action="/step2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
        <input type="submit" value="upload" >
    </form>
```

Upon post, I am able to get the image via self.request.get('datafile'), and this appears to be a binary data type ('str'). I put this into a database, and I can display this with:

```
    self.response.out.write('<div><img src="img?img_id=%s"></img>' % userimages.key())
```

I am struggling to find a way to convert this into a PIL.Image data type, in order to do image processing with it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the string in a `StringIO` object:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

imgfile = StringIO(self.request.get('datafile'))
img = Image.open(imgfile)
```

All PIL needs is a file-like object; `StringIO` provides this source the actual data from the given string.

In the other direction, have `PIL` write to a `StringIO` object, but you do need to specify the format used:

```
imgfile = StringIO()
img.save(imgfile, format='PNG')
imagestring = imgfile.getvalue()
```

Comment: Thanks, and how would I do the reverse? example:
bg = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (512, 512), "white")
db.Blob(str(bg))
Does not seem to work

Comment: @JessMcintosh: Added information about how to get an image datastream out of a PIL image too.